# How can I block specific requests in a website with a userscript?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to prevent block a specific GET request made by YouTube. When the searchbar is clicked, a GET request to `https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com/complete/search?...` is performed, which fetches search-suggestions. I don't want these search suggestions.

I tried clearing cookies, and turning it off in the settings but to no avail. So then I tried it with Tampermonkey.

Here is what I tried:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube URL Blocker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Block GET requests to specific URLs on YouTube.
// @author       me
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var blockedURL = "https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com/complete/search";

    document.addEventListener("beforesendheaders", function(e) {
        var requestDetails = e.detail;
        if (requestDetails.method === "GET" && requestDetails.url.startsWith(blockedURL)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("GET request to blocked URL blocked:", requestDetails.url);
        }
    });

})();
```

This unfortunately did not work. The request was still appearing and the `console.log()` also did not execute.

I then tried:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

    var blockedURL = "https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com";
    
    window.originalFetch = window.fetch;
    
    window.fetch = function(url, options) {
        if (url.startsWith(blockedURL)) {
            console.log("Fetch request to blocked URL:", url);
            return;
        } else {
            return window.originalFetch(url, options);
        }
    };

})();
```

Sadly, this had the same results and did not work either.

My last attempt was:

```
var blockedURL = "https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com";

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    if (this._url && this._url.startsWith(blockedURL)) {
        console.log("XMLHttpRequest blocked:", this._url);
        return;
    }
    this.realSend.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GM_webRequest`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_webRequest):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube URL Blocker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Block GET requests to specific URLs on YouTube.
// @author       me
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        GM_webRequest
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const blockedSelector = 'https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com/complete/search*';

    GM_webRequest([
        { selector: blockedSelector, action: 'cancel' },
    ], (info, message, details) => {
       console.log('GET request to blocked URL blocked:', info, message, details);
    });
)();
```

or [`@webRequest`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:webRequest):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube URL Blocker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Block GET requests to specific URLs on YouTube.
// @author       me
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @webRequest   {"selector":"https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com/complete/search*","action":"cancel"}
// ==/UserScript==

// rest of code
```

In this case, `GM_webRequest` and `@webRequest` have almost identical behaviour — only difference is that with `@webRequest`, the blocking rule is applied as soon as possible (i.e. before the userscript is loaded).

Comment: Thanks! How did you find out about that? Do you by chance know a good place where I can learn more about tampermonkey's built in features?

Comment: @derpascal no better place to learn about TM features other than TM's official documentation :)

Comment: Does this still work? I am breaking my head here and eslint also says that @webRequest is not a valid userscript thing

Comment: @Thorvarium the reason eslint shows a warning is because Tampermonkey uses an older version of [eslint-plugin-userscripts](https://github.com/Yash-Singh1/eslint-plugin-userscripts). The code should work and is not affected by that warning.

Comment: I've figured out the issue. Apparently @webRequest doesn't block sendBeacon requests.