# Javascript, only run if tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am running a script which prevents a particular website from logging out by refreshing the page every few minutes. The issues I have is that the refresh occurs even if I am actively using the page.

I would like the following script to run only if the current tab running the page is inactive.

Do I need to use some type of event handler or can I simply call on the page visibility API and run if state = 'any other state than visible'?

Very new to javscript :)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Tony TIMS Refresh
// @namespace   TonyPony
// @description Reload pages every 1 minutes
// @version      0.2
// @match   
// @match https://THE PAGE I WANT TO REFRESH
// @match 
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 60*1000);
})();
```

I am not sure how I would implement either of my suggestions.

Comment: You can block the logout request as well. See [How can I block specific requests in a website with a userscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77337532)

Comment: Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting one as the "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer). Doing that will acknowledge the answer and close out the question, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community. You receive points each time you close out a question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Page Visibility API. This API allows you to determine if a tab is currently active or not, and based on that, you can choose to run your script or not.

```
// check if browser supports Page Visibility API
if (document.visibilityState) {
  // add event listener for visibilitychange event
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  // check if current tab is inactive
  if (document.visibilityState !== "visible") {
    // run your script here
    console.log("Tab is inactive, running script...");
  }
}
```

note: that not all browsers support the Page Visibility API, so you may want to implement a fallback method using the `onblur` event handler as well.

```
window.onblur = function() {
  // code to refresh page here
};
```

Comment: But beware that when your tab isn't active, most browsers now throttle your code's use of timers and such, so this may not be effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior of refreshing a page only when the tab is inactive using the Page Visibility API in JavaScript. This API allows you to determine whether the current tab is visible or hidden to the user.

Here is a simple example script that demonstrates this functionality:

```
<script>
    var reloadInterval = 1000; // Set the reload interval in milliseconds

    if (document.hidden !== undefined) {
        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);
    }

    function handleVisibilityChange() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            console.log('Tab is inactive. Refreshing page...');
            setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, reloadInterval) 
            //Refresh the page after the specified interval
        }
    }
</script>
```

This script will refresh the page at a defined interval only when the tab is inactive. You can adjust the reloadInterval variable to set the desired time interval for refreshing the page. Run this script in an HTML file and check the console to see the page refresh when the tab is inactive.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

TJ Crowder's comment below Afzal's answer is critical - modern browsers will reduce iterations of your code to only once per minute, or less.

There is a solution: web workers. For some reason, just adding a web worker to your code will reduce the throttling to whatever interval there is communication with the web worker.

Here is a simple webworker that re-awakens your script every second:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    if (e.data === 'run the timer') {
        setInterval(function() {
            self.postMessage('timer tick');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```